# $(selector).each on table rows w/ Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5

this is my first question here and I've been searching for a long time about this, also I'm more than a newbie on jQuery and JavaScript in general, but I need it for very small tasks right now so I just got into it without a very deep knowledge of it.

I'm using Laravel 5.4, and I have a table which body is made of a loop on rows because I need it to show results from database, not that it matters, but just for the sake of explaining. I gave an id to an icon that if clicked it will perform some actions, first of all rendering a confirm message and then deleting the row if yes is clicked.

The problem is that I can make that rendered if the first row's icon is clicked, but not for the others.
I tried the each method but it seems that's not working, and probably I misread the documentation or I'm not understanding its usage

My code for that is really simple (not performing the delete task):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#delete').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            return!! confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
        });
    });
});
```

I just want to make the confirm box appear for every icon I click on!

Thanks in advance! If you need me to update the question with some more information please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be worth giving [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) a read when you get a moment. Understanding the difference between unique identifiers and class names will help you progress with your learning.

Moving on to your issue, the best practice will be to use class names instead of unique identifiers. Where possible, change the `id="delete"` on the elements to `class="delete"`. This way we are able to bind the confirmation dialog on any element whether it is already in the DOM, or added at a later time.

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
  return !!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
});
```

If you're adding rows that contains this button via AJAX then you'd want to bind the function as so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
  return !!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess I'm not a newbie just on jQuery lol, thanks for helping me out, this solved my problem, and thanks for the reference that I will read for sure!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on a containing element to get events fired on all contained `#delete` elements.

```
$('body').on('click', '#delete', function(ev) {
    return!! confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
});
```

If you need to keep info on exactly which element was clicked, it's available (for ex) in `ev.target`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ID attribute more than once. I suggest you use classes (like `class="delete"`) instead, and use this :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
       return!! confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
   });
});
```